# Confusion in making a decision tree classifier

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

I want to predict students play cricket or not{Target Variable}.
Suppose I have 3 columns :
Gender, Class, Age 
As we can see, I have 2 categorical attributes and one continuous attribute.
While deciding the root node, I know that both categorical attributes can be compared traditionally using gini criterion. How should I split the continuous attribute and which criterion should I take into account for it to be considered as a competitor for being the root node against 2 categorical?

Answer (score 1):

You can split continuous variables in intervals. Lets suppose you have continuous variable form 1 to 10, You can split it like 1 to 5 in one category and 6 to 10 in different category.

Comment: Just to clarify. So will decision tree classifier check all the possible bins such as <1 and >=1 , <2 and >=2 and so on... depending on which will give us the best information gain?

Comment: according to my example its like <=5 and >=6

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on which model (algorithm) you are using for doing the splitting. However, In generel the F-test is what normally what is used when splitting continuous variables. Try to have a look at what SAS uses for their implementation: [SAS - splitting criteria](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/68162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_hpsplit_details02.htm). Also, here is a quite good explanation of decision trees: [Decision tree. It begins here](https://medium.com/@rishabhjain_22692/decision-trees-it-begins-here-93ff54ef134).